# How to say "workaround/quick-and-dirty hack"

Tags: word-requests

How to say "workaround/quick-and-dirty hack" in Japanese in the context of computer programming?

ALC says 次善策 for "workaround" but of course it does not convey the sense of dirtiness/fragility/speed I am looking for.

Context: quick email about a software feature, to my superior, with whom I am on very friendly terms but still use -ます form for instance.

Comment: In what context? A formal communication? A follow-up to a bug report? A code comment?

Comment: Sorry good remark, I will add details.

Comment: I don't have the confidence to add this as a proper answer, but perhaps one of the compounds of 応急 fits here? 応急策 ( [band-aid solution](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/band-aid+solution) ,  [quick fix](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/ej3/68611/m0u/) ), for instance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the jargon word (ダーティ)ハック！
Simple and direct.

You could also say something like 適当な解決方法、適当なやり方

Answer (score 5):

Besides Hyperworm and rdb's answers,

> その場しのぎ

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's used specifically in programming, but やっつけ仕事 might give the sense you want. I wouldn't use it a formal context. There's always the all-purpose 臨機応変のX, which you probably could use formally.

Comment: I think that やっつけ仕事 is more focused on sloppiness than what “quick-and-dirty hack” suggests, but I am not completely sure about the nuance of “quick-and-dirty hack.”

Comment: You're probably right, but since I'm not a programmer myself, I'm not really sure either. The meaning of "quick-and-dirty" by itself is pretty loose, I think, but definitely implies a lack of refinement. At the time I posted, the OP had not yet clarified the intended context, so I figured I'd throw out a couple of suggestions at opposing levels of formality.

Comment: I am afraid that my comment was not clear.  What I meant is that やっつけ仕事 _is_ sloppy, not that the _word_ やっつけ仕事 is informal.  If you use a “quick-and-dirty hack” as part of your project at work, I guess that it is ok depending on the context, but if you do やっつけ仕事, it is not good.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear either. What I meant to say was, depending on the formality of the situation, I would use different words. i.e., if I were talking to a colleague or friend, I might say, "I just threw something together, but it works for now." But to a supervisor I would probably say "I managed to find an interim solution."

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation.  I am still not sure about the comparison of applicability of “quick-and-dirty hack” and “やっつけ仕事,” but I guess that to really explain it, we need a software engineer who is fluent in both English and Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

May be 裏ワザ can be use for some cases.

Comment: I see this especially in writings aimed at non-experts. Many books about hacks or tricks for OSes have 裏技 in their title.

Comment: It sounds very systematic, unlike a hack which is ad hoc…

Comment: It seems to already have been taken:  http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/exception+operation